# Как получить данные из пост запроса в контролере в symfony 2.8?

Tags: php, json, post, symfony2

Я посылаю данные из Postman, к примеру, с двумя полями(title, description). В заголовке "Content-Type : application/json".
Как мне получить данные из этого запроса в контролере?

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
   //при использовании
   $content = $request->getContent();
   //в $content лежат данные типа
   /*
   string 
   '------WebKitFormBoundaryEYTeSQWUB74Utzqn
   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="title"

   "supertitle"
   ------WebKitFormBoundaryEYTeSQWUB74Utzqn
   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"

   "superdescription"
   ------WebKitFormBoundaryEYTeSQWUB74Utzqn--
   ' 
   (length=264)
   */
}
```

Как получить из $content нужные поля и данные или сериализовать в удобный тип?
И еще, как обрабатывать приходящие в запросе изображения?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Для **POST** запроса:

```
$request->request->get('data');
```

Для **GET** запроса:

```
$request->query->get('data');
```

Для **FILE**:

```
$request->files;
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы поставили только заголовок `application/json`, нужно ведь и данные в `json` отправлять.

В `Postman` при создании есть вкладка `raw`, в ней записываются `json` данные для отправки на сервер.

Для отправки файлов необходимо использовать `multipart/form-data`, и работать с `$_FILES` как обычно.

Answer (score 0):

```
//in request is json array; 
public function indexAction(Request $request){
    //for POST request;
    $data = $request->request->all(); //for POST
    print_r($data);
    //return;

}
```